# Program Simulation Techniques

Tags: static-analysis, simulation, dataflow

I've noticed that data-flow analysis uses *approximations* of a programs steps by simulating the value flow in some way (which I don't fully understand yet). They describe it well [here](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~aldrich/courses/15-819O-13sp/resources/dataflow-frameworks.pdf). On page 4 they say:

> Because the analysis is not tracking the exact values of variables, but rather approximations, it will inevitably be imprecise in certain situations.  However, in practice well-designed approximations can often allow dataflow analysis to compute quite useful information.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data-flow_analysis) also says it nicely:

> A simple way to perform data-flow analysis of programs is to set up data-flow equations for each node of the control flow graph and solve them by repeatedly calculating the output from the input locally at each node until the whole system stabilizes, i.e., it reaches a fixpoint.

I'm wondering why don't they just actually run the program with specific combinations of variables to test it out and determine if it is "correct" that way (like the advantages/disadvantages). Also wondering what the other approaches and techniques are to simulating a program other than dataflow analysis.

Comment: Read wikipage on [abstract interpretation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_interpretation) and on [Hoare logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoare_logic). Play with [Frama-C](http://frama-c.com/) & [Clang analyzer](http://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/). Both are documented free software, so study their implementation

Comment: I feel your question is really too broad. You could follow some graduate course on static source code analysis (for at least an entire year). And the wording "program simulation" is a poor choice (it is related to emulators, not to static source code analyzers)